# How to decode JSON list using sql statements in AWS IoT core?

Tags: sql, arrays, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot

> Here I have displayed the payload that I am trying to decode in AWS
>   IoT core rules to push that to AWS DynamoDB.

```
{
    "adr": true,
        "applicationID": "1",
        "applicationName": "IOTAPPS",
        "data": "AANl3AAAQT8AZA==",
        "devEUI": "sadfgxvgsfxgs245",
        "deviceName": "TRON002",
        "fCnt": 0,
        "fPort": 2,
        "object": {
          " A1": "NO",
          "A10": "YES",
          "A11": "YES",
          "A12": "YES",
          "EGHmpID": 222684,
          "SelFFMac": 100,
          "TOTAL_DATA": "100000100111111"
        },
        "rxInfo": [
          {
            "gatewayID": "FDFDFEF5584EDEef",
            "location": {
              "altitude": 0,
              "latitude": 12.66885,
              "longitude": 77.81253
            },
            "name": "IoTGateway",
            "fddi": -94,
            "time": "2019-11-18T09:02:08.895349Z"
          }
        ],
        "txInfo": {
          "dr": 5,
          "frequency": 898678700000
        }
    }
```

We are trying to fetch 'time' from 'rxInfo' list by using following sql statement.

```
SELECT deviceName,(SELECT VALUE time FROM rxInfo) AS time FROM "my/topic"
```

We are not getting the expected answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's tested on AWS IoT.

```
SELECT (SELECT time fROM rxInfo) AS time FROM "abc/cmd"
```

to generate this output:

```
{
  "time": [
    {
      "time": "2019-11-18T09:02:08.895349Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

cheers,
ram

Comment: We tried your command, by making the time as primary key in dynamo db. We are not at all getting any output. Please upload the screen shot of the result in the dynamodb and the command in the IoT console if possible.